# Display AppSetting.json as a "versioned or nested" File In Visual Studio UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a `.NETStandard` library & need to add (versioned) JSON files by configuration-environment.  The trick is...I want to see if it is possible to setup the Project File (.proj) to list them in the same manner they would if it was a Web.Config file.

FOR EXAMPLE:
A web.config will display this way in Visual Studio
[image: Web Config by-environment]

It accomplishes this by doing the following in the .PROJ file:

```
<None Include="Web.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Web.ModelOffice.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Web.Release.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Web.Development.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Web.Production.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

So, to be clear...

[image: Desired Effect]

But this does NOT work in a `.NETStandard` library...

```
<None Include="appsettings.json" />
<None Include="appsettings.development.json">
  <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="appsettings.modeloffice.json">
  <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="appsettings.production.json">
  <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Integrated file nesting in Solution Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer)
2. There is a [FileNesting extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting), written by [Mads Kristensen](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/MadsKristensen).

   But beware, this extension has some limitations on the following project types (from the `Known issues` section of the extension description):

   > - Node.js projects (NTVS)
   > - ASP.NET Core (has built in rules for nesting)
   > - Apache Cordova
   > - Shared projects

In an unsupported project type (e.g. `.NETStandard` library), add the following to your project file & the "Add Custom Settings" option will automatically appear in your "Solution Explorer" toolbar. (Note that [this is a workaround](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/4463#issuecomment-594639018) and not an official solution)

```
  <!-- I added this node to enable "Custom File Nesting" -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectCapability Include="DynamicDependentFile" />
    <ProjectCapability Include="DynamicFileNesting" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After that...

- Name your custom files accordingly (settings.json, settings.debug.json etc)
- And set the "Standard Settings" option to "Web" in the "Add Custom Settings" option

Comment: Is there a way to do it WITHOUT a 3rd Party component?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO Yes, there is integrated file nesting in Solution Explorer. (I've added it to my answer)

Answer (score 14):

In .NET 5, you can do this via the `DependentUpon` tag in your `.csproj` file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="appsettings.Production.json">
    <DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```